# Prove that $H=\{i,(12),(34),(12)(34)\}$ forms a non-cyclic subgroup of $S_4$.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

> We have to prove  that $H=\{i,(12),(34),(12)(34)\}$ forms a non-cyclic
>   subgroup of $S_4$.

It is seen that there is no element of order $4$ in $H$. So,  $H$ is non-cyclic. But How can I show $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Is there any shortcut method?

Comment: Very closely [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1289774/11619). This group has been handled so many times. Did you search the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labeling, $a=(12)$, $b=(34)$. You have $a$ and $b$ commute ($ab=ba$) and $a^2=b^2=i$. From the previous facts, it's not difficult to see that $H=\{i,a,b,ab\}$ is closed under the group operation, so it is a subgroup. In fact $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by the map given by $a\mapsto (1,0)$ and $b\mapsto (0,1)$.

Comment: product of disjoint cycles is not commutative in general? right?@JulianMejia

Comment: If the cycles are disjoint then their product is always commutative. But of course a product of permutations in general might be not commutative.

Comment: If $a=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ and $b=(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_m)$ are disjoint cycles (i.e. $x$'s and $y$'s don't intersect). Then you have that $ab=ba$. Because $a$ permutes the $x's$ and $b$ is permuting the $y$'s. It doesn't matter if you do first $a$ and then $b$ or viceversa, you get the same thing since $x$'s and $y$'s are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's enough to show it is closed (it is almost obvious here), since $H$ is finite; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547233/a-closed-finite-subset-of-a-group-is-subgroup).